# SwiftUI - CustomAlertView - Run function with parameters on Button press

Tags: swift, parameters, alertview

I have a CustomAlertView with the following parameters:

```
    public var title: String
    public var buttonText: String
    public var buttonAction: (() -> ())?
```

... a dedicated function is called via:

```
Button(action: {buttonAction() })
```

I can run the code and any functions with the following

```
   customAlert = CustomAlertView(title: "Item found",
                                      buttonText: "Take it",
                                      buttonAction: closePopup
        )

    showCustomAlert = true

...

  func closePopup() { showCustomAlert = false }
```

I want to add some functions with parameters e.g.

```
 closePopupAndGetItemWithID(1)
```

but I cannot call them, and it states:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(() -> ())?'

how do I need to convert the var in my CustomAlertView to allow functions with and without parameters?

can anyone explain what this means: (() -> ())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new closure that calls the function with the argument:

```
CustomAlertView(
   title: "Item found",
   buttonText: "Take it",
   buttonAction: { closePopupAndGetItemWithID(1) }
)
```

Regarding your second question:

> can anyone explain what this means: (() -> ())?

It's a type annotation for a closure in Swift. The first `()` is the arguments for the closure (no arguments in this case). The second is the return value -- you're very likely to see this as `Void` in other codebases. Then, it's wrapped in parenthesis to group it as one statement and the `?` makes it an optional.

Additional reading:

- http://goshdarnclosuresyntax.com
- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html